# Removing unneeded classes that ProGuard fails to remove

Tags: android, android-proguard

I have an android project. Originally it's size was 240 KB. Today, I added to it a toolbar. All of the changes were a little addition in the `layout` folder in `res`, a small icon and two lines in my main activity. Also, it made the project depend on android-support-v4/7... This made the project jump in size to 1,425 KB. If I use ProGuard to compile, the size "shrinks" to 923 KB, still much larger then the original file.

By looking at the code decompiled, I see many class files that i'm sure I didn't use (All I have is a little toolbar, and that's it. Also, my class directory weighs 34 KB, but android's class directory weighs 995 KB after ProGuard).

Does android's toolbar really call all those classes, or am I missing something in ProGuard? I have no `-keep` in the `proguard-project` file, and it does (a small part of) its job.